# rlang::last_error() when grouping using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I am using dplyr to group my target variable and it normally works but Im not sure why I am getting this error. My code is as simple as:

```
class_percentage <- bank_dataset %>% group_by(y) %>% summarise(count = n())
```

I get this error:

> Error: This function should not be called directly
>   Call `rlang::last_error()` to see a backtrace

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: do you have `dplyr` as well as `plyr` loaded together? Can you restart your R session and then load **only** `dplyr` and check if it works ?

Comment: Cannot reproduce this error. @RonakShah is spot on. It's due to conflicts with `plyr`.

Comment: yes it works when I remove plyr! Thank you